# Admissible solution space for PDE: $L^2(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I really hope this question is not too silly...

If we have a PDE, say something like
$$
u_t=u_{xx} + \sin u,
$$
is it then admissible to search for solution in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ or do we have to assume more like $L^2(\mathbb{R})\cap C^2(\mathbb{R})$ since functions in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ do not have to be differentiable?

Comment: This is way more complicated than can be answered here. Weak solutions to PDEs are definitely a thing, and they have less regularity than the strong formulation of the PDE suggests they should. But reading off what space the weak solutions to a PDE live in is quite complicated in general.

Comment: There are several things I am wondering about. One is that a solution $u$ seems to be a function of $(t,x)$ i.e. on $\mathbb{R}^2$, say. So, in which way might it be admissible to look for solution in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$? Another thing is, as mentioned, that functions in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ do not need to be differentiable. Hence it might make no sense to talk about partial derivatives.

Comment: Yes, a solution is on $\mathbb{R}^2$, but the regularity required in each variable is not the same. So a priori you would look for solutions to that equation which are $C^1$ in $t$ and $C^2$ in $x$. Really though, just look up something about weak solutions to PDEs. You'll get the general idea from there. As an example, the natural space to look at the Poisson equation $\Delta u = f$ on a bounded domain $U$ with certain boundary conditions is $u \in H^1$, also known as $W^{1,2}$, with $f \in L^2$.

Comment: (Cont.) The former is a Sobolev space of functions which are square integrable with square integrable weak derivative.

Comment: For the Poisson equation you mentioned, a solution $u$ is again a function depending on $(t,x)$, isn't it? But since we only have the partial derivatives with respect to x in the equation we can ignore t (or maybe it is better to say that t is fixed so that in fact we are only interested in solution $u(t,\cdot)$) so that it is enough to find an appropriate solution space (here $H^1$) w.r.t. $x$?

Comment: In the Poisson equation there is not generally any $t$ at all. Anyway, again, in a weak solution you don't have to have all the derivatives that appear in the strong form of the equation. For example, the weak form of the Poisson equation only requires the weak derivative of a solution to exist as an $L^2$ function.

Comment: Okay. For my original PDE, when I see it right, we can write $u_t=-\nabla_{L^2}E(u(t,\cdot))$ for $E(u(t,\cdot)):=\int_R \frac{1}{2}u_x^2+F(u)\, dx$, where $F'(u)=-\sin u$ and $\nabla_{L^2}E(u(t,\cdot))=-u_{xx}-\sin u$. Moreover, as far as I see, this only holds, if we assume that $v\to 0$ as $\lvert x\rvert\to\infty$.  - - Since $v$ has to be out of the same solution space as $u$, my question is what would be an admissible solution space.  - Sorry, maybe this is much too confusing. But I am thinking about that already too long...

Comment: $\cos(u)$ is not a functional; that maps a function to another function. You need an actual functional in that term to have an $L^2$ gradient there. Anyway, you don't necessarily need to pose the problem as a gradient flow. It's convenient for certain purposes, such as checking existence/uniqueness/regularity, but it's not critical.

Comment: I meant that $E(u(t,\cdot))$ is the functional

Comment: Oh, the $dx$ was further along than I than I thought. That might work, but you have a peculiar problem: there is little reason to believe that $\cos(u)$ should be integrable. In particular it can't be if $u$ is.

Comment: Why would I need that cos(u) is integrable?

Comment: You wrote $\int F(u) dx$, so you're assuming $F(u)=\cos(u)$ is integrable, no?

Comment: But it isn't? Sorry, I am confused.

Comment: Under normal circumstances you would have $u \in H^1$ in which case $\lim_{|x| \to \infty} u(x)=0$ hence $\lim_{|x| \to \infty} \cos(u(x))=1$ so $\cos(u)$ wouldn't be integrable.

Comment: Then please one last question. How do you get from $u\in H^1$ that $\lim_{\lvert x\rvert\to\infty}u(x)=0$?

Comment: The short answer is "Sobolev embedding". (I might actually be slightly mistaken that you have *quite* enough regularity for this, but I am still pretty sure that you can't have $\cos(u) \in L^1$ if $u \in L^2$).

Comment: Ok! Then maybe one variation: What, if instead we are considering $u_t=u_{xx}+\cos u-1$. Then, we would have the same as above but $F(u)=-\sin(u)+u$. In this case, we should have $u_t=-\nabla_{L^2}E(u)$ for $u\in H^1$?

Comment: That sounds about right, yes.

Comment: Okay, then it is admissible to say that we can search for solutions $u\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ with $u(\cdot,x)\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $u(t,\cdot)\in H^1(\mathbb{R})$? Is this a convenient way to express that?

Comment: That's likely more regularity than you necessarily want to assume. You'll want to look up "mixed spaces" to have a good feel for the right way to think about this (which essentially amounts to a certain space of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $H^1(\mathbb{R})$).